# maybe, i've erased something from laravel and I have this error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
 [ErrorException]
  include(A:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\composer/../../database/migrations/20
  16_08_15_023851_create_categories_table.php): failed to open stream: No s
  uch file or directory
```

I cannot make a migration, because I have that error. How will I fix my laravel to original

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory. Reading this can help you understand what could be happening

Answer (score 3):

Migrations are files that you create. Only two migrations, `users` and `password_resets` are included with Laravel and they are not required.

Confirm that the file exists. A common problem is that people create the migration and there is a mismatch between the file name and the class name.

For file name `2016_08_15_023851_create_categories_table.php` the class name declaration must be `class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration`.

When the file path and class name declaration are correct this error can still occur because the autoloader is not updated.

Running `composer dump-autoload` will resolve this issue.